# Comparing two pandas Series where elements are comma-separated strings with vector operation

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, record-linkage

I am creating a custom comparison algorithm for the recordlinkage Python library. My function takes two pandas Series as arguments, where each element of the series is a list of one or multiple phone numbers. So an example of the series would look like this:

```
series1 = pd.Series([
"1234567890,0987654321",
"0987654321"
])

series2 = pd.Series([
    "0987654321",
    "1234567890,0987654321"
])

0    1234567890,0987654321
1    0987654321
dtype: object

0    0987654321
1    1234567890,0987654321
dtype: object
```

Then I am passing the series to the following function which performs a lambda function operation on the resultant concatenated DataFrame:

```
    def _compute_vectorized(self, ph1, ph2):
    """
    Applies lambda function compare_phones to all elements of the two equal-sized Series.

    :param ph1: First series where each element is a comma-separated string of phone numbers.
    :param ph2: Second series where each element is a comma-separated string of phone numbers.
    :return sim: Series of similarity coefficients calculated between both input series.
    """

    ph_df = pd.concat([ph1, ph2], axis=1)
    ph_df.columns = ["ph1", "ph2"]
    sim = ph_df.apply(lambda x: self.compare_phones(x["ph1"], x["ph2"]), axis=1)

    return sim
```

Here is the lambda function being performed on the DataFrame:

```
from strsimpy.normalized_levenshtein import NormalizedLevenshtein

nl = NormalizedLevenshtein()

def compare_phones(self, ph_str_1, ph_str_2):
    """
    Compare comma-separated strings of customer's phone numbers. If any phone numbers match between the sets,
    return a similarity value of 1. Otherwise, compute the normalized Levenshtein distance between the two
    comma-separated strings.

    :param ph_str_1: First comma-separated string of phone numbers.
    :param ph_str_2: Second comma-separated string of phone numbers.
    :return sim: Float similarity coefficient between the two comma-separated strings of phone numbers.
    """

    if len([ph for ph in ph_str_1.split(',') if ph in ph_str_2.split(',')]) > 0:
        sim = 1
    else:
        sim = nl.distance(ph_str_1, ph_str_2)

    return sim
```

Essentially, if any phone numbers match between the two columns, we get a similarity coefficient of 1. Otherwise, the function determines the normalized Levenshtein distance between the comma-separated strings of phone numbers using strsimpy library.

This operation has significantly slowed down my total comparison logic, but it is necessary to perform this custom algorithm on phone numbers. My question is...is there a way I can perform this as a vector operation on the input series (or concatenated df of the two series)? I know this would be faster, but I cannot wrap my head around how to do it exactly.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Look at my code below, I've simplified it to the maximum :)

I'm using a different module tan you to find Levenshtein distance, but it's tiny and fast.

```
import pandas as pd

df = ({'A':["1234567890","5555555555","0987654321"], 
       'B':["1237654890","4444444444","0984567321"]})
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

list1 = df.A.tolist()
list2 = df.B.tolist()

# !pip install fuzzywuzzy
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

# list1 = ["1234567890","5555555555","0987654321"]
# list2 = ["1237654890","4444444444","0984567321"]

for i in list1:
  for j in list2:
    Ratio = fuzz.ratio(i,j)
    print(f'Between {i} and {j} the ratio is {Ratio}.')
```

Output:

```
Between 1234567890 and 1237654890 the ratio is 70.
Between 1234567890 and 4444444444 the ratio is 10.
Between 1234567890 and 0984567321 the ratio is 40.
Between 5555555555 and 1237654890 the ratio is 10.
Between 5555555555 and 4444444444 the ratio is 0.
Between 5555555555 and 0984567321 the ratio is 10.
Between 0987654321 and 1237654890 the ratio is 40.
Between 0987654321 and 4444444444 the ratio is 10.
Between 0987654321 and 0984567321 the ratio is 70.
```

**FuzzyWuzzy** documentation [here](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/).

Comment: thanks, unfortunately this doesn't answer the question as you're also just using nested for loops (which df.apply(lambda x) is using under the hood) rather than vector operations